# How to mock MongoDb in Jest (Nest.js)

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

Well now I am testing a Nest.js application that uses mongodb ,and everywhere I saw people saying "dont use a testdb in unit tests,you should mock everything but the actual functionality you're working" ,and wel ,I'm trying to do this without any success LOL XD... I am using native driver to manipulate the db,something like

```
const user = await this.db
      .collection('users')
      .findOne({ email: loginData.email });
```

and when testing services I dont know how to mock it in jest without using a test db

Do anyone here have any idea what to do? (by the way thanks so much for reading until here)

Answer (score 3):

This might help you: https://github.com/nodkz/mongodb-memory-server
And also, you should be mocking the data in your unit tests. Unit tests are to verify the functionality of your functions or methods.